# Remove some elements from array and re-size array in C

Tags: c, arrays

**Regards**
I want to remove some elements from my array and re-size it.
for example my array is:

```
char get_res[6] = {0x32,0x32,0x34,0x16,0x00,0x00};
```

Now I want to remove elements after 0x16, so my desire array is:

> get_res[] = {0x32,0x32,0x34,0x16};

what is solution?

Comment: You can't resize a statically allocated array like this! And maybe you don't need to, why do you want to?

Comment: Looks a bit like an XY-problem. Do you want  delete `0x00`s specifically or **any** character beyond `0x16` (imagining there are others)?

Comment: @iharob This array received from USART and I must sent it to my another USART without after 0x16 (end frame) elements.

Comment: @EhsanDavoudi So just send the part of it you want to send. There's no need to modify the array.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot resize arrays in C (unlike Python, for example). For real resizing, at least from an API user's point of view, use `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, and `free` (`realloc` specifically).

Anyway, "resizing" an array can be imitated using

- a delimiter; for example, a delimiter like `0xff` could mark the end of the valid data in the array

  Example:

  ```
  #define DELIMITER 0xff

  print_data(char* data) {
      for (size_t i = 0; data[i] != DELIMITER; ++i)
          printf("%x", data[i]);
  }
  ```
- a member counter; count the number of valid data from the beginning of the array onward

  Example:

  ```
  size_t counter = 5;

  print_data(char* data) {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
          printf("%x", data[i]);
  }
  ```

---

Notes:

- Use `unsigned char` for binary data. `char` may be aliasing `signed char`, which you might run into problems with because `signed char` contains a sign bit.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to "remove" them. Just don't access them. Pretend like they don't exist. Same like in stacks, when you "pop" a value from the top of the stack, you just decrement the stack pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating arrays in C isn't easy as it is for vector in C++ or List in Java. There is no "remove element" in C. I mean that you have to do the job yourself, that is, create another array, copy only the elements you want to this new array, and free the memory occupied by the previous one.

Can you do that? Do you want the code?

EDIT:

Try that. It's just a simple program that simulates the situation. Now, you have to see the example and adapt it to your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char get_res[6] = {0x32,0x32,0x34,0x16,0x00,0x00};
    char target = 0x16;
    int pos, i, length = 6; // or specify some way to get this number
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if(get_res[i] == target) {
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    pos = pos + 1; // as you have to ignore the target itself
    char *new_arr = malloc(pos);
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        new_arr[i] = get_res[i];
        i++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        printf("%c ", new_arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if it possible please

Comment: That's why it's not neceesary to actually remove it, just ignore it. And that's precisely why [tag:c] is still a better language.

Comment: That's definitely not the way to go in C. Copying the data is inefficient as hell. In case one ends up actually copying it, she/he should use `memcpy` anyway. What if there are 65536 bytes to copy? Also, `%c` is for printable characters. This is binary data.

Comment: Man, he can remove the printf() function. It doesn't matter in this context. The author just want to know how to remove elements. As there is no way to do that the way he wants, I presented a simple program. Of course, the parts that don't matter for the context, he can change as they aren't part of the problem. If he wants to use memcpy, it's his business (don't get offended, please) :)

Comment: @cad I don't think you need to dv ONLY for what you exposed. I'm not asking for remove the dv, but just because you answered too, you don't need to keep dv'ing other's answer. That's not the way to go, man. Keep the advice. ;)

Comment: I won't, don't worry. :-) It's just by posting an answer here, you try to answer something, serving as an idol to other learners. So, how would a beginner know that he can remove the `printf` part? How would he know to prefer `memcpy`? He'll just apply your code and will perpetuate bad habits.

Comment: Idol? That's huge. I don't wanna be an idol for learners. Well, I think he's learning C, so he doesn't need to learn the best way to do every single thing. Printing, copying, etc. By the way, your answer doesn't answer his question, IMO.